# Unable to deploy on Eth mainnet

Tags: solidity, remix, contract-deployment, evm

i done all the steps and when im connecting to "Injected provider" its still asking to be on EVM version: shanghai. i want to deploy the CA on the mainnet.

[image: attach an example.]

Comment: Can you provide more information about the error message and the steps you are taking? Does your wallet have enough ETH to pay for the deployment cost? Is your contract compiled without any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Do not worry. The word displayed above shows that you have correctly connected to the Ethereum mainnet network, because the ID being displayed is 1.
Please continue with the steps of deploying and verifying your contract.